# How to list `cannot resolve symbol` warnings in groovy code? (IntelliJ)

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I want to list all `cannot resolve symbol` warnings in my groovy code. I set severity level of `Groovy->Probable bugs->Access to unresolved expression` in my inspection profile to `Warning`. IntelliJ does highlight the `cannot resolve symbol` warnings in edit view but it does not list the problems in the list of problems after I run `Analyze->Inspect Code...`.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2.

Running inspection on the following piece of groovy code responds with a message `No suspicious code found` though `fooo()` is highlighted.

```
class Example {
  def foo() {
    fooo() // highlighted as `Cannot resolve symbol 'fooo'`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for static compilation behavior.  Please use @CompileStatic for it

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Example {
    def foo() {
        fooo() // highlighted as `Cannot resolve symbol 'fooo'`: shows as error in IJ14
    }
}
```

Comment: It does help but it doesn't answer my question so I cannot accept it as an answer.

Comment: You may clarify question bit more. What you are looking is , IMHO, more capabilities from IDE.  IntelliJ team is active here.